# Can I compile (protect) a python script?

Tags: python, compiling

I have a python script.  It starts with #!/usr/bin/env python
Is there a way I can compile it, and protect it's contents?
I've used shc for bash scripts, and before anyone chimes in with a moan, I know it's not a secure way to protect the contents of the script.

I was hoping there was a secure way to compile a python script and completely stop anyone from seeing the original code.

If not, then maybe something like shc would do, to stop the ill informed from snooping.

Hope that makes sense.

Preston

Comment: This doesn't seem to be about Ubuntu, but a general programming question. As such, it is off-topic here and should instead rather be asked on e.g. [so]. However, I think there is already a post that fully covers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/261638/4464570

Comment: :( Sorry, will do that

Comment: Keep in mind almost anything compiled and be decompiled. Also when compiled with debug / trace options it is even easier to decipher when decompiled.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't try it myself, but I know there's a thing called [cx_Freeze](https://anthony-tuininga.github.io/cx_Freeze/). From its description:

> cx_Freeze is a set of scripts and modules for freezing Python scripts into executables

I'm not sure how easy or hard it is to unpack executable and actually see the script source in it, so security of this approach is debatable.

Answer (score 0):

I have used one Python compiler during initramfs to speed up boot time for [EnhanceIO](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/EnhanceIO) SSD to HDD block device cacher. It worked well back in 2016 but I don't know how well it compiles today in current Python language.

The compiler used is called [Pyinstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) and it:

> is a program that freezes (packages) Python programs into stand-alone
>   executables, under Windows, Linux, Mac OS X, FreeBSD, Solaris and AIX.
>   Its main advantages over similar tools are that PyInstaller works with
>   Python 2.7 and 3.3—3.6, it builds smaller executables thanks to
>   transparent compression, it is fully multi-platform, and use the OS
>   support to load the dynamic libraries, thus ensuring full
>   compatibility.